# UIButton scale vector graphic

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I use vector graphics in my app and would like the image to be bigger. Unfortunately all posts I found on this just scaled the image, not using the through vector graphics available higher resolution.

```
photoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width/3.0*2.0-15,
                                                                       15,
                                                                       width/3.0,
                                                                       height/3.0)];
    [photoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [photoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(photo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an image of what you mean. I don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: have you looked at the property `contentScaleFactor`?

Comment: @Fogmeister What I mean is that I can not tell the Button to recalculate the image for a higher resolution

Comment: @Johannes ok, added an answer. I think I see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, what you're seeing is a result of how the vector images are used in ios and os x. They are not stored as vector images in the compiled bundle. The vector image is used, at compile time, to create all the required standard and retina versions of the image. These are then stored as png files in the bundle and the png file for the screen resolution (standard, 2x, 3x retina) are used to display them.

What you probably want is to use a resizable image. For this you can't use vector images you have to provide a png. Then you can "slice" the image into resizable and non-resizable sections.

For instance you can create a button background image that will resize to the button dimensions and keep the corners nice and rounded by making sure the corners are not distorted.

Take a look at the "show slicing" options in the asset catalog in Xcode.

Comment: I don't understand the thinking at Cupertino for this. Users download their apps over cellular networks all the time. Why not just support vector images like Windows does, so users can have a smaller download size. Some Universal Apps that do this can end up with a much larger overall app size :/